# Why is the row() function not known in my macro?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

This macro is stopping with a compile error:

> "sub or function not defined"

and `Row` is highlighted.

I am using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365.

```
Sub test()
    Range(Address(Row(), Column()) & ":" & Address(Row(), Column() + 5)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect `Row()` and `Column()` to be? And what do you expect `Address` to do? What is the purpose of your code? The entire syntax is wrong. Please [edit] your question and explain **in words** what your code should do.

Comment: Maybe you are after `ActiveCell.Resize(, 5).Select` or `Selection.Offset(, 5).Select`. Please let us know.

Comment: Please make sure to clarify your intention and what you want to do with your code. it helps others to understand your intention. others can help you only if they can understand you or your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ROW Function ... If reference is omitted, it is assumed to be the reference of the cell in which the ROW function appears.[Row function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d%5D)

As your sub-routine, `test`, isn't in a spreadsheet it wouldn't have the function defined.  You might be interested in the [Row attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) of Range.

Comment: The macro is in a spreadsheet. My intent is to replace, for example, "D13:I13" in Range("D13:I13").Select with something that could be used in any currently active cell.

Comment: Your sub not defined in a cell, right?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe.

```
Sub GetRowNumberFromCellAddress()
Range("A10").Select ' example

Dim col, row
col = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(1)
row = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(2)

MsgBox "Column is : " & col
MsgBox "Row is : " & row
 
End Sub
```

Check out the link below, for more info.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All! Researching your comments was very educational. The tips from CBasic2008, especially, put me on the right track. What I was trying to do was this:

```
Sub test()
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Select
End Sub
```